# Husky & Prettier [error] Cannot read property '' of null

Tags: javascript, prettier, husky

I have set up a husky hook for a react app, for eslint and prettier, though when I commit and the prettier script runs I get this error:

```
> eslint  --fix src/**/*.js


> prettier src/**/*.js --write. --config ./.prettierrc
[error] Cannot read property '' of null
> husky - pre-commit hook exited with code 1 (error)
```

I have checked the entire app for this '' null condition though have found nothing.

.prettierrc

```
{
    "arrowParens": "always",
    "bracketSpacing": true,
    "embeddedLanguageFormatting": "auto",
    "htmlWhitespaceSensitivity": "css",
    "insertPragma": false,
    "jsxSingleQuote": false,
    "proseWrap": "preserve",
    "quoteProps": "as-needed",
    "requirePragma": false,
    "semi": true,
    "singleQuote": false,
    "trailingComma": "es5",
    "useTabs": false,
    "vueIndentScriptAndStyle": false,
    "printWidth": 150,
    "tabWidth": 4,
    "rangeStart": 0
}
```

package.json

```
"scripts": {
        "start": "react-scripts start",
        "build": "react-scripts build",
        "test": "react-scripts test",
        "eject": "react-scripts eject",
        "lint": "eslint  --fix src/**/*.js",
        "format": "prettier src/**/*.js --write. --config ./.prettierrc",
        "prepare": "husky install"
    },
    "eslintConfig": {
        "extends": [
            "react-app",
            "react-app/jest"
        ]
    },
    "husky": {
        "hooks": {
            "pre-commit": "npm run lint && npm run format"
        }
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "eslint": "^7.32.0",
        "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.3.0",
        "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.0.0",
        "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.27.1",
        "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.3.0",
        "husky": "^7.0.4",
        "prettier": "^2.5.1"
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is typo in format script, you can just put it as

`"format": "prettier src/**/*.js --write"`